# vue-tiny-slider: Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: t2 is not a function

Tags: javascript, vue.js, slider, carousel

I use Vue 3. I installed vue-tiny-slider https://github.com/viktorlarsson/vue-tiny-slider, but it shows me an error 't2 is not a function'. The documentation doesn't cover the setup for Vue 3, so I tried to set it up on my own.

Here's my template:

```
<template>
    <div class="my-slider">
        <vue-tiny-slider
            :mouse-drag="true"
            :loop="false"
            :items="2"
            :gutter="20">
            <div
                v-for="recipe in storeRecipe.popularRecipes"
                :key="recipe.recipe_id">
                <ItemCard :recipe="recipe" :pending="storeRecipe.pending" />
            </div>
        </vue-tiny-slider>
    </div>
</template>
```

And the script:

```
<script setup>
import ItemCard from '@/component/ItemCard.vue';
import { onMounted, h } from 'vue';
import { useStoreRecipe } from '@/store/storeRecipe';
const storeRecipe = useStoreRecipe();

import VueTinySlider from 'vue-tiny-slider';

const render = () => {
    return h(
        VueTinySlider,
        {},
        {
            default: () => (this.$slots.default ? this.$slots.default() : []),
        }
    );
};

onMounted(async () => {
    render();
    await storeRecipe.loadPopularRecipes();
});
</script>
```

I'm looking for a possible solution.

Comment: you could try a vue tiny-slider made for vue3 - like https://www.npmjs.com/package/@mentorkadriu/vue-tiny-slider

Comment: @JaromandaX 1.25 MB ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

extend VueTinySlider in a new .js file, modify the `render` code there, then import the updated slider into the SFCs you want to use it in.

**tinyslider.js**

```js
import { defineComponent, h } from 'vue'
import VueTinySlider from 'vue-tiny-slider'

export default defineComponent({
  extends: VueTinySlider,
  render() {
    return h('div', this.$slots?.default ? this.$slots.default() : {})
  }
})
```

**Component.vue**

```html
<template>
  <div class="my-slider">
    <vue-tiny-slider :mouse-drag="true" :loop="false" :items="2" :gutter="20">
      <div v-for="recipe in storeRecipe.popularRecipes" :key="recipe.recipe_id">
        <ItemCard :recipe="recipe" :pending="storeRecipe.pending" />
      </div>
    </vue-tiny-slider>
  </div>
</template>
```

```js
<script setup>
import VueTinySlider from './tinyslider.js'
import { onMounted } from 'vue';
import { useStoreRecipe } from '@/store/storeRecipe';
const storeRecipe = useStoreRecipe();

onMounted(async () => {
    await storeRecipe.loadPopularRecipes();
});
</script>
```

Comment: It worked, thanks! I still think that this slider is a bit broken. For example, things like nav bullets won't appear, or if I set `controls: false,` in the options, the controls are still present.